# pip install -e, Python path and namespace packages

Tags: python, pip, python-import, pythonpath

I have a package layout like this

```
myproject/
    setup.py   # contains package info for "myproject" package
    myproject/ # contains various Python source files
    deploy/    # contains non-package Python scripts for deployment tools
    tests/ 
    ...
```

From inside the top level `myproject` folder if I issue `pip install -e .` (this is within a conda environment), then the path `/path/to/myproject` ends up being part of `sys.path` all the time.

For example, if I make a new clone of the `myproject` repo and store it in a new folder such as `myproject2`, say, then do some work in an interactive interpreter in that folder, I find that `sys.path` will still have `/path/to/myproject` automatically at startup.

My hunch is this is happening somehow because `pip install -e` will symlink the files from `/path/to/myproject` into `site-packages` or another suitable location, and the module system initialization in Python must do some special processing where it follows the symlink and adds the source directory to the path automatically.

The issue I am having is for (non-package) scripts within `deploy/` that use absolute imports to reference other scripts in the same folder (since they are intended to be executed from the top level of `myproject`), how can I prevent Python from instead finding only the copy of this folder that exists for the particular clone of `myproject` that used `pip install -e` and thus appears on the Python path?

**Added**

It also strikes me as a point of confusion what would happen with namespace packages in this case. For example, if the `deploy/` folder does not have an `__init__.py` file, but you are executing things from the `/path/to/myproject` working directory (or otherwise have that in the Python path), then in Python 3.3+ it will be treated as a namespace package which can span directories.

So what happens if I have both

```
/path/to/myproject   # which has been installed with pip install -e
/path/to/myproject2  # not installed, extra clone of the same project
```

then if I am over in `/path/to/myproject2` dealing with the `deploy/` scripts, can they end up being viewed as a namespace package that also includes `/path/to/myproject/deploy/` since `/path/to/myproject` is always in the Python path by virtue of `pip install -e`?

Then the final question would be what impact this can have on absolute vs. relative imports and import priority inside of that "mega" `deploy` namespace package that accidentally spans two directories.

Comment: Are you using [virtual environments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) to isolate your projects from each other?

Comment: @sinoroc yes, as mentioned in the question, all of this takes place in a single, isolated conda environment.

Comment: I would recommend using multiple virtual environments instead (usually 1 virtual environment for each project or clone of the project is a good measure), I believe this should solve your issue. Would that be possible? ... The question contains several (loosely related) questions, it's not easy to answer those all at once. If I were you I would ask these questions separately if you are interested in the details.

Comment: @sinoroc I think you are misunderstanding the question. This is not an issue about multiple virtual environments. The same issue could arise if instead of a second copy of `myproject` I had some other project folder with a ghosted `deploy/` namespace package name, and it may be a requirement that it is installed in the same virtual env right along `myproject`. This is a question about incidental effects of namespace packages when combined with `pip install -e` of a local working repo.

Answer (score 2):

It's the [`easy-install.pth`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/site.html) file in the `site-packages` directory that has an effect on the value of `sys.path`. This effect does not depend on the currently working directory. I am still not entirely sure what role exactly the [`*.egg-link`](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/deprecated/python_eggs.html#egg-links) file plays in the `site-packages` directory (although it is indeed meant, at least partly, as a platform-independent substitute for symlinks).

As for the namespace packages... Let's consider the following directory tree:

```
.
├── alfa
│   ├── bravo
│   │   ├── one.py
│   │   └── zero.py
│   └── zero.py
├── foo
│   ├── bar
│   │   ├── two.py
│   │   └── zero.py
│   └── zero.py
└── src
    ├── alfa
    │   ├── bravo
    │   │   ├── three.py
    │   │   └── zero.py
    │   └── zero.py
    └── foo
        ├── bar
        │   ├── four.py
        │   └── zero.py
        ├── __init__.py
        └── zero.py
```

All `*.py` files contain the following:

```
print(__name__, __file__)
```

Notice how there is only one package initializer `src/foo/__init__.py`.

The modules `alfa.bravo.one` and `foo.bar.two` are importable because the current directory is always on the Python interpreter's search path (`sys.path`):

```
$ python3 -c 'import alfa.bravo.one'
alfa.bravo.one /home/sinoroc/workspace/so-59682278/alfa/bravo/one.py
$ python3 -c 'import foo.bar.two'
foo.bar.two /home/sinoroc/workspace/so-59682278/foo/bar/two.py
```

But importing `alfa.bravo.three` and `foo.bar.four` is not possible:

```
$ python3 -c 'import alfa.bravo.three'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'alfa.bravo.three'
$ python3 -c 'import foo.bar.four'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'foo.bar.four'
```

This is the case because they are in the `src` directory, and that directory is not on Python's *path*:

```
$ python3 -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)'
['', '/usr/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.6', '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/home/sinoroc/workspace/so-59682278/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
```

A directory can be added to Python's path, by writing its location in a `.pth` in the interpreter's `site-packages` directory:

```
$ echo "${PWD}/src" > '.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/test.pth'
$ python3 -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)'
['', '/usr/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.6', '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/home/sinoroc/workspace/so-59682278/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/home/sinoroc/workspace/so-59682278/src']
```

And now it is possible to import `alfa.bravo.three` and `foo.bar.four`:

```
$ python3 -c 'import alfa.bravo.three'
alfa.bravo.three /home/sinoroc/workspace/so-59682278/src/alfa/bravo/three.py
$ python3 -c 'import foo.bar.four'
foo /home/sinoroc/workspace/so-59682278/src/foo/__init__.py
foo.bar.four /home/sinoroc/workspace/so-59682278/src/foo/bar/four.py
```

The module `alfa.bravo.one` is still importable, thanks to namespace packages:

```
$ python3 -c 'import alfa.bravo.one'
alfa.bravo.one /home/sinoroc/workspace/so-59682278/alfa/bravo/one.py
```

But since the package `foo` from the `src` directory has an initializer, `foo` is not a namespace package anymore and the module `foo.bar.two` can not be imported:

```
$ python3 -c 'import foo.bar.two'
foo /home/sinoroc/workspace/so-59682278/src/foo/__init__.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'foo.bar.two'
```

Now for the `zero` modules it's a bit more surprising. There are modules with the exact same import path in both the current directory and in the `src` directory:

```
$ python3 -c 'import alfa.zero'
alfa.zero /home/sinoroc/workspace/so-59682278/alfa/zero.py
$ python3 -c 'import alfa.bravo.zero'
alfa.bravo.zero /home/sinoroc/workspace/so-59682278/alfa/bravo/zero.py
$ python3 -c 'import foo.zero'
foo /home/sinoroc/workspace/so-59682278/src/foo/__init__.py
foo.zero /home/sinoroc/workspace/so-59682278/src/foo/zero.py
$ python3 -c 'import foo.bar.zero'
foo /home/sinoroc/workspace/so-59682278/src/foo/__init__.py
foo.bar.zero /home/sinoroc/workspace/so-59682278/src/foo/bar/zero.py
```

If there is no initialized package (`alfa`), then the version in the current working directory is imported. But if there is one version with an initializer (`foo`), then this is the version from the initialized package that is imported.

**Notes**

- Python 3.6.9